# Приведение типов умных указателей C++

Tags: c++, smart-pointer

А можно ли привести тип умного указателя родительского класса к дочернему? К примеру есть есть базовый класс Models и от него наследуется класс Staff. Вот сам пример:

```
void StaffsModel::addItem(std::shared_ptr<Models> item)
{
    std::shared_ptr<Staff> ptrStaff = (std::shared_ptr<Staff>)item;
    Staff *newStaff = ptrStaff.get();
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Приводить тип `std::shared_ptr` можно при помощи специальных функций:

- [`std::static_pointer_cast`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/static_pointer_cast/) - аналог `static_cast`
- [`std::dynamic_pointer_cast`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/dynamic_pointer_cast/) - аналог `dynamic_cast`
- [`std::const_pointer_cast`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/const_pointer_cast/) - аналог `const_cast`

То что вы хотите сделать называется "понижающее приведение типа". Его возможно выполнить через `static_cast`, но безопаснее будет использовать `dynamic_cast`.

```
void StaffsModel::addItem(std::shared_ptr<Models> item){
    std::shared_ptr<Staff> ptrStaff = std::dynamic_pointer_cast<Staff>(item);
    Staff *newStaff = ptrStaff.get();
    //...
}
```

**PS:** Конкретно в вашем примере не вижу никаких препятствий сделать

```
void StaffsModel::addItem(std::shared_ptr<Models> item){
    Staff *newStaff = dynamic_cast<Staff*>(item.get());
    //...
}
```

Comment: К сожалению ни первый, ни второй случай не работает... Хотя второй мне очень приглянулся

Comment: @БалунВладимир, "не работает" это сильно абстрактно. Что именно не работает?

Comment: Выходит ошибка приведения типов, и выбивает на исходник shared_ptr.h

Comment: @БалунВладимир для dynamic_cast и dynamic_pointer_cast класс должен быть полиморфным. И для dynamic_cast нужно указывать к чему приводить - к указателю или ссылке, т.е. ```dynamic_cast<Staff*>(item.get())```

Comment: @БалунВладимир, а ваши типы точно наследники? А виртуальные функции есть?

Comment: @Croessmah, а вы правы, у меня опечатка. Исправил

Comment: Как раз таки addItem переопределяется ф-ия от предка

Comment: Ну тогда давайте минимальный воспроизводимый пример. Должно работать. Или хотя бы ошибку

Comment: Уже работает спасибо, за помощь

Answer (score 4):

Для преобразования shared_ptr имеются функции:
std::static_pointer_cast - подобие static_cast
std::dynamic_pointer_cast - подобие dynamic_cast
std::const_pointer_cast - подобие const_cast

```
std::shared_ptr<Staff> ptrStaff = std::static_pointer_cast<Staff>(item);
std::shared_ptr<Staff> ptrStaff = std::dynamic_pointer_cast<Staff>(item);
```

Answer (score 0):

Получилось вот так, может кому-нибудь пригодится

```
std::shared_ptr<Staff> ptrStaff = std::static_pointer_cast<Staff>(item)
Staff *newStaff = ptrStaff.get();
```

Comment: "Пригодиться" это никому не может в принципе, т.к. ответы из разряда "я не знаю почему, но вот так сработало...." бесполезны полностью.

Answer (score -1):

Нет смысла делать еще один локальный умный указатель, просто приводите по ссылке:

```
auto newStaff{dynamic_cast<Staff *>(item.get())};
```

Если же хочется именно еще один умный указатель, то следует использовать `dynamic_pointer_cast`:

```
auto ptrStaff{::std::dynamic_pointer_cast<Staff>(item)};
```

И в том, и в другом случае получившийся указатель может быть нулевым и его обязательно следует проверить перед использованием. Кроме того, для работы `dynamic_cast` должна быть включена поддержка рантайм информации о типах.