# Сравнение полиморфных объектов по указателям

Tags: c++, полиморфизм

У меня есть иерархия классов `Money`, `Dollar` и `Franc`, моделирующие деньги. Нужно в стиле ООП реализовать следующее:

- Умножение денег на число
- Сравнение денег
- Протестировать код

Я написал так:

```
#ifndef MONEY_H
#define MONEY_H

#include <memory>

using std::shared_ptr;
using std::make_shared;


class Dollar;

class Money
{
public:
    static shared_ptr<Money> dollar(int amount);
    virtual shared_ptr<Money> times(int value) const = 0;
    virtual bool equals(shared_ptr<Money> money) const = 0;
protected:
    int amount;
};

class Dollar : public Money
{
public:
    Dollar(int amount);
    shared_ptr<Money> times(int value) const override;
    bool operator==(const Dollar& dollar) const;
    bool equals(shared_ptr<Money> dollar) const override;
};

class Franc : public Money
{
public:
    Franc(int amount);
    shared_ptr<Money> times(int value) const override;
    bool operator==(const Franc& franc) const;
    bool equals(shared_ptr<Money> dollar) const override;
};

#endif


#include "money.h"

#include <gmock\gmock.h>

shared_ptr<Money> Money::dollar(int amount)
{
    return make_shared<Dollar>(amount);
}

Dollar::Dollar(int amount)
{
    this->amount = amount;
}

shared_ptr<Money> Dollar::times(int value) const
{
    return make_shared<Dollar>(amount * value);
}

bool Dollar::operator==(const Dollar& dollar) const
{
    return amount == dollar.amount;
}

bool Dollar::equals(shared_ptr<Money> dollar) const
{
    if (dynamic_cast<shared_ptr<Dollar>>(dollar))
    {
        return true; // TODO
    }
    return false;
}

Franc::Franc(int amount)
{
    this->amount = amount;
}

shared_ptr<Money> Franc::times(int value) const
{
    return make_shared<Franc>(amount * value);
}

bool Franc::operator==(const Franc& franc) const
{
    return amount == franc.amount;
}


using ::testing::Eq;

TEST(Money, TestDollarMultiplication)
{
    shared_ptr<Money> five = Money::dollar(5);
    ASSERT_TRUE(five->times(2) == Dollar(10));
    ASSERT_TRUE(five->times(3) == Dollar(15));
}

TEST(Money, TestFrancMultiplication)
{
    const Franc five(5);
    ASSERT_TRUE(five.times(2) == Franc(10));
    ASSERT_TRUE(five.times(3) == Franc(15));
}
```

Возникли проблемы из-за тестов. Нужно сравнивать деньги между собой. Поскольку я работаю с указателями из-за полиморфизма, это приносит дополнительные неудобства.

Оказалось, что после перехода с объектов на указатели тест перестал компилироваться:

```
TEST(Money, TestDollarMultiplication)
{
    shared_ptr<Money> five = Money::dollar(5);
    ASSERT_TRUE(five->times(2) == Dollar(10));
    ASSERT_TRUE(five->times(3) == Dollar(15));
}
```

Сначала я использовал оператор сравнения, но теперь понадобилась функция equals для сравнения по шаред поинтерам.

```
bool Dollar::equals(shared_ptr<Money> dollar) const
{
    if (dynamic_cast<shared_ptr<Dollar>>(dollar))
    {
        return true; // TODO
    }
    return false;
}
```

Нужно убедиться в том, что сравниваются указатели на объекты одного типа. Для этого я использую **RTTI**, но такое применение `dynamic_cast` приводит к ошибке.

Как сделать правильно?

Comment: см [Приведение типов умных указателей C++](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/766531/Приведение-типов-умных-указателей-c/766543). Другое дело, что ни иерархия полиморфных классов, ни `shared_ptr`, ни `dynamic_cast` для решения такой задачи особо не нужны...

Comment: Почему не нужны? Как тогда использовать полиморфизм и скрыть низкоуровневые классы за интерфейсом Money?

Comment: Да и полиморфизм тоже не особо нужен. Достаточно сделать один класс с двумя полями - количество и валюта.

Comment: Из того, что вы пока написали, совершенно не понятно, что вам нужно сделать. Сравнение полиморфных объектов, типа валют (т.е. когда разные типы фактически сравнимы) - классическая задача на double dispatch. Тем не менее у вас вдруг проверка на совпадение типов сделана. Это действительно нужно так сделать?

Answer (score 0):

Реализовывать сравнение через dynamic_cast - плохая идея. В случае, когда сравнивать можно только деньги одной валюты - это еще терпимо, но сравнивать разные валюты будет проблематично. Лучше ввести некоторую базовую валюту (не наследника money), в которую можно конвертировать любую другую при помощи соответствующего виртуального метода, а уже эти базовые валюты сравнивать.

Кроме того, все случаи использования shared_ptr в вашем коде не имеют смысла. В большинстве случаев можно использовать unique_ptr, местами вообще можно создавать объекты на стеке.

Передавать объекты в функцию через shared_ptr - тоже плохая идея, если только внутри функции не происходит сохранения указателя в качестве побочного эффекта. В функции на подобие equals аргументы лучше передавать по константной ссылке на базовый класс, а уже при вызове приводить указатель к ссылке.

Функция times по идее не должна создавать новый объект, достаточно модифицировать старый. Но если хотите - возвращайте опять же unique_ptr, а не shared_ptr.

Ну и непосредственно по ООП: базовый класс обычно ничего не должен знать о своих наследниках, иначе теряется его смысл.